# Object reference not set to an instance of an object - how to find error in a medium project

Tags: vb.net, nullpointerexception, webforms, nullreferenceexception

My system (WEBFORMS VB.NET) has presented a null object exception (**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**), which only happens on the production server after an undetermined period of time.

That is:
After resetting the pool the application returns to normal, but after a while the exception returns. And when the error happens ** ALL ** the project pages are inaccessible, requiring a reset of the pool.

---

[image]

- The error does not produce a message specifying a specific page or line
- It has already been verified and all connections to the DB are being closed / opened correctly
- The project has a considerable number of pages, classes etc.
- The compiler does not report any variables or warnings

---

Is there any way to get to the root of the error?

Comment: look at the stacktrace error. it gives you a hint of a null PipelineModuleStepContainer or something related. if its not enough, try to wrap the suspicous code and on exception write a log file or another log with the full stacktrace error and then copy it to here

Comment: Bit of a longshot, but add this to global.asax and see if you get more details (sorry for the lack of formatting of code):        
    `Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim ex As Exception = Server.GetLastError()
        If TryCast(ex, System.Web.HttpUnhandledException) IsNot Nothing Then
            Throw ex
        End If
    End Sub`

Comment: Asi, I looked the stacktrace error and I didn't find the error or exception.  The project is quite extensive and it is difficult to isolate parts without a minimum direction, but I am trying to

Comment: Jeff Mergler I inserted your code snippet, however there was no change in the error message